# How to cut out part of a string and insert into other string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have unknown number of strings (assume 3 )

```
  <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
```

I want to cut out a.html, b.html and c.html. Then put them into the following structure with given a string MyLink = http://ccc.com/

```
randomlinks[0]="http://ccc.com/a.html"
randomlinks[1]="http://ccc.com/b.html"
randomlinks[2]="http://ccc.com/c.html"
```

What functions in Vb.net allow me to do that?

Comment: String.IndexOf, String.Substring. But, unless you have total control on the structure of the input data, I recommend to use a specific library that can handle the HTML text (Html Agility Pack) for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a simple search and replace VB program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849554/how-to-do-a-simple-search-and-replace-vb-program)

Answer (score 0):

If your strings *always* have this *exact* format, [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) is your friend.

```
myString.Split(""""c)
```

with `myString` containing the first of your strings will yield a three-element array with the following entries:

- `<li><a href=`
- `a.html`
- `>A</a></li>`

How to proceed from there should be obvious and is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

---

If the strings *don't* always have this *exact* format, a HTML parsing engine is probably the right tool.